# Track QR-Codes with google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, qr-code

I want to do advertising for my app with QR codes- stickers. I want to track them with google analytics to know how many downloads comes from the stickers. Firstly I used the URL Builder: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?rd=2

But this gives me just a link, which is not connected in any form to my google analytics account. How do I link these qr codes to my analytics account? Thank you

Comment: Likely when you added your URL to the URL builder, you entered in the URL to your website. So when somebody visits your website with that URL builder generated URL, GA will pickup the campaign params and you'll see your campaign metics in GA.

Comment: Thank you... just one more thing: how can I add these params in GA? I never found these fields :( (ps. if you answer below, i'll mark it as correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely when you added your URL to the URL builder, you entered in the URL to your website. So when somebody visits your website with that URL builder generated URL, GA will pickup the campaign params and you'll see your campaign metics in GA.

You don't add the params in GA, you add them in the [URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en). So, for example, you let's say you want the Campaign Source to be Google, the Campaign Medium to be Display, and the Campaign Name to be Awesome Campaign, you would put these values into the URL Builder, and click 'Submit'.

[image]

Once you click 'Submit', you'll get a copy of the URL you can add to your QR code generator.

[image]

When a visitor visits your site using that link, you'll see it noted in GA under Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns.